# how can I use php with javascript tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form. I want to alert when the user click on save button. Then if the user clicked yes, some php code should be executed. So how can I do it. can I use onclick in input tag???

```html
 <?php if (isset($_POST['save'])){ ?>
<script language="javascript">
     if (confirm('It should be reloaded, Are you sure you want to save changes?')) {
  <?php $x=$_POST['myName']; ?>
  }
  else{
   <?php $x='nothing' ?>
   }
    </script>
    <?php }
 echo $x;
 ?>
<form method="post" action="">
 name:<input type="text" name="myName" />
    city:<input type="text" name="city" />
    email:<input type="email" name="email" />
 <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to know that PHP code is executed **before** the user receive html/js page. So, once he receive the page you can't execute PHP directly. But what do you want exactly ?

Comment: I want to alert the user. If user is sure some php function (like shell execute()) should be execute...

Comment: What is your idea, how can I do it?

Comment: If you want alert user before submit the form, you should do a confirm, and if the user confirms you can do an ajax request to execute PHP on the server. Otherwise, you can't execute PHP directly from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
  <?php 
    // connection 
    if ($_POST['t'] == 'execute'){
       <?php $x=$_POST['myName']; ?>
    }else{
      <?php $x='nothing' ?>
    }
  ?>
<form method="post" action="">
   name:<input type="text" name="myName" />
   city:<input type="text" name="city" />
   email:<input type="email" name="email" />
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="t" value="execute"/>
  <input type="submit" name="save" onclick="return confirm('you message')" value="save"/>
</form>
```